# Dynamic SQL with Identifier in psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

```
int1 = "first"
int2 = "second"
column1 = ['height', 'test1', 'test2']
column2 = ['height', 'width']

int1_attr = [sql.Identifier(int1,s) for s in column1]
int2_attr = [sql.Identifier(int2,s)for s in column2]

qry_str = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} as (Select {},{}, st_intersection({},{}) from {},{} )").format(
sql.Identifier('Intersection'),
sql.SQL(', ').join(int1_attr),
sql.SQL(', ').join(int2_attr),
sql.Identifier(int1+".geom"),
sql.Identifier(int2+".geom"),
sql.Identifier(int1),
sql.Identifier(int2)
)
print(qry_str.as_string(con))

>> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Intersection" as (Select "first"."height", "first"."test1", "first"."test2","second"."height", "second"."width", st_intersection("first.geom","second.geom") from "first","second" )
```

Hey, I need for example "first"."height" as "first.height" in select part but for all attributes. That code is what I could do. I can't make any progress from that. Is there any way to it?

At the end sql should look like this;

```
>> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Intersection" as (Select "first"."height" as "first.height", "first"."test1" as "first.test1", "first"."test2" as "first.test2" ,"second"."height" as "second.height", "second"."width" as "second.with", st_intersection("first.geom","second.geom") from "first","second")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *int1_attr* you're just identifying the columns with `"table"."column"`. What you need to do is build *int1_attr* as `"table"."column" AS "table.column"`. That can be done using:

```
int1_attr = [
    sql.SQL("{} AS {}").format(
        sql.Identifier(int1, s),
        sql.Identifier("{}.{}".format(int1, s))
    ) for s in column1
]
int2_attr = [
    sql.SQL("{} AS {}").format(
        sql.Identifier(int2, s),
        sql.Identifier("{}.{}".format(int2, s))
    ) for s in column2
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! I just used it in `sql.Composed(int1_attr).`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Identifier` to create qualified column name:

```
NAMED_EXPRESSION = '%s as %s'
QUALIFIED_NAME = '%s.%s'
int1_attr = [
    NAMED_EXPRESSION % (
      sql.Identifier(int1, s),
      sql.Identifier(QUALIFIED_NAME % (int1, s))
    ) for s in column1
]
```

Comment: You teach me a lot right there. But with these, it can't work with sql.SQL().
Thanks btw.